# Cannot Restore Database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, restore

I have two servers the source server is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) 
Jun 28 2012 08:36:30 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

The destination server is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3373.0 (X64) 
Jun 29 2013 21:15:12 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

If I create a new database on the source server (2008 R2), take a backup if it and then try to restore that backup to the destination server (2012) I get the following:

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
>   The media family on device 'c:\databases\Testbackup.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.

All of the other threads I can find are for people trying to restore from a newer version of SQL to an older version. That is not what I am doing.

I can restore the backup onto the original server, I can also create a backup of a database on the 2012 server and restore it from the same location I am doing my test from so I don't believe it is a permissions issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe your BAK is corrupt.

Comment: Have you tried taking a separate backup, to a different file name, and ensuring you use `WITH INIT`?

Comment: I tested it home few times. Backups from 2008r2 Standard restored and worked with no issues on 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any 3rd party tools on your 2008 R2 source instance that aren't on your destination?

I just ran into an issue where HyperBac (legacy) was still enabled on the 2008 R2 source instance and wasn't installed on the 2012 destination instance which was the problem.

Good luck!